# How do I get back to the current working copy while viewing git revisions?

Tags: git, plugin-fugitive

When using `:Glog` or other git plugins like `:GV` (`gitv`?) and checking revisions or commit you end up in Read-Only mode viewing something like

```
fugitive:///.git//300ed70aa473b7e8f983a2590c2af908cd0a0621/file
```

Is there a way to get to the original `file` in the current working tree?

This is especially handy when using `:Glog` and stepping back in time, to get back to "now".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Gedit` command is here for you.

It takes an argument which is the revision you want to use, using the same logic as [git-rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) (meaning you can use it without argument to get back to your working copy), so, on your file, type

```
:Gedit
```

And you're back to your working copy.

References:

- `:h fugitive-:Gedit`
- `:h fugitive-revision`

Comment: Vimcasts episodes: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/)